# Http Post Fails when Trying to Post JSON Data that contains XML

Tags: c#, json, http, http-post

I'm trying to do an http post with the following function. It works fine with my post data contains normal JSON data (just text). But now my json data also contains xml in one of it's fields.

```
 public string postJSON(string username, string password, string endPoint, string json)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(endPoint, "POST", "text/json");
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        try
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.WriteToLog("RequestMaker", "postJason function: " + ex.Message);
            return "error";
        }          
    }
```

But I'm getting a bad url error (400) when I try to do so.
My endpoint URL looks something like this:
http://se.api.anpdm.com/v1/import/mailinglist/#####/demographicmapping/###
And a sample Json code that has to posted looks like this.

```
"{\"XMLData\":\"<Subscribers><Subscriber><Name>Pedram</Name><Email>mobedi@live.com</Email><DemographicData><Demographic mapTo='Urval'>30</Demographic></DemographicData></Subscriber><Subscriber><Name>Anders Svensson</Name><Email>pmobedi@yahoo.com</Email><DemographicData><Demographic mapTo='Urval'>27</Demographic></DemographicData></Subscriber></Subscribers>\"}"
```

Is there something else I should do?

Comment: What is the version of framework you are using on your application?

Comment: Do you have access to the endpoint documentation or code? The problem is with the request or request data, not necessarily the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Framework 4.0., this can be because of your web server validation configuration settings, which denies to send xml or other tags in the body of your requests. If it is so, try to change your RequestValidationMode to 2.0 in your web section of web.config:

```
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Comment: mine is actually a console application where can i change that?

Comment: You must change it on your server, not client. It is the server setting which makes it to filter all requests with '<' tag symbols. Where do you send your web request? Is it IIS?

Comment: it is a RESTful service on the internet.

Comment: Than, if this service has a configuration to filter requests with XML, you would not be able to send such requests.

Comment: but i don't think that's the case on their side because they're already using these functions. so should i change the .net framework version on my side?

Comment: No, the version of your framework doesn't affect your request. It is hard to say something definitly without seen the configuration of REST service. I had the same problem with XML requests, and it was in the the validation rule of the service I used to call.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer,
Small stupid things:
“XMLData” is wrong. It should be “XmlData” exactly as the Json parameter written in the server.